# ColdFusion cfmail is sending emails twice or thrice

Tags: java, email, coldfusion, lucee

I am using Lucee. Here is the code.

```
<cfmail to="info@gmail.com" 
        from="some@gmail.com" 
        cc="some2@gmail.com" 
        bcc="some3.gmail.com" 
        subject="Testing mail system">
    <cfoutput>#dateformat(now(),'dd-mm-yyyy')#</cfoutput>
</cfmail>
```

When I remove the cc and bcc from above it is working as expected, but when I add cc, it is sending email twice and if I add bcc as well then it is sending email thrice. I don't know what is the issue. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: is the configuration done twice or maybe ***thrice*** ???

Comment: My expected behaviour of your code is that it will throw an error due to the cfoutput tag.  Also, what are you looking at to determine how often the mail is being sent?

Comment: What configuration you are talking about?

Comment: I am looking at .eml files that are generating on server. When I run this code each time three .eml files are generating.

Comment: If I use cc it is sending twice and if I use cc and bcc then sending thrice.

Comment: @user1927648 .eml files generated by what? Coldfusion generates cfmail files. The mail server will be generating the eml file. This might be the behaviour of that product.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in this ! The mail should go to CC and BCC email addresses right ? If so, it'll be one or more emails depending upon the no of email addresses used in TO, CC and BCC fields.